# Implementing the ability to scroll (when needed) to phones that might be too small

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollviewer, dimensions

I have tested my app in a debugger for many different sizes, and realized I will probably need a scrollView to allow the user to view the full layout.

The issue, is I use a flipper in my main.xml with multiple linear layouts like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/your_flipper"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     <!-- the second view on the flipper -->
    <!-- ImageView -->
    <!-- TextViews -->
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <!-- Image Buttons -->


</LinearLayout>

<!-- the 3rd view on the flipper -->
<!-- ImageView -->
<!-- TextViews -->
<!-- Buttons -->
<!-- Image Buttons -->


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

</LinearLayout>

<!-- the 4th view on the flipper -->
<!-- ImageView -->
<!-- TextViews -->
<!-- Buttons -->
<!-- Image Buttons -->


</LinearLayout>
```

I made the ImageViews, Buttons, TextViews, etc comments so not to bloat the code -

This is in my main xml file, where all the layouts are displayed.  How can I go about easily adding a scroll view to each layout, so if it is too big for the screen of a certain phone, the user can scroll through the page to see all the content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping each `LinearLayout` (each child of the `ViewFlipper`) with its own `ScrollView`. While you could wrap the whole `ViewFlipper`, this is not as modifiable in the future if, for example, you didn't want one view to scroll.

Comment: A `ScrollView` will only provide scrolling if the contents is larger than the size of the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to wrap the layout (the main linearlayout or something you create as the container)

with a 「scrollView」 ,

like this :

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/